# How do I do an Oracle SQL update from select?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have created a query for updating a table from another table. The field is updating as expected for a given date. The problem is that for other dates, I am now getting NULL values on the column I updated. How do I set the new value only for the specific date and not affect the other dates?

Table A:

```
| ID | VALUE |      ADD_TIME        |
-------------------------------------
| 1  | -5    |1/11/2019 10:45:11 am |
```

Table B:

```
|AS_OF_DATE| ID | VALUE |
-------------------------
|2/29/2019 | 1  |  -4   |
|1/31/2019 | 1  |  -4   |
|12/31/2018| 1  |  -4   |
```

Desired Output:

```
|AS_OF_DATE| ID | VALUE |
-------------------------
|2/29/2019 | 1  |  -4   |
|1/31/2019 | 1  |  -4   |
|12/31/2018| 1  |  -5   |
```

Current Output:

```
|AS_OF_DATE| ID | VALUE |
-------------------------
|2/29/2019 | 1  |       |
|1/31/2019 | 1  |       |
|12/31/2018| 1  |  -5   |
```

My Query:

```
update TABLEB
set VALUE =
(
  select VALUE from TableA
  where ID = '1'
  and TABLEB.AS_OF_DATE < TABLEA.ADD_TIME
)
```

Comment: `TABLEA` has only one row? Than  simple add `WHERE b.AS_OF_DATE < (select ADD_TIME from TABLEA)` to the UPDATE

Comment: Pls check your data types: `2/29/2019` is **not valid date**;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an `exists()` check so rows which don't have a match aren't updated:

```
update TABLEB
set VALUE =
(
  select VALUE from TABLEA
  where ID = '1'
  and TABLEB.AS_OF_DATE < TABLEA.ADD_TIME
)
where exists
(
  select VALUE from TABLEA
  where ID = '1'
  and TABLEB.AS_OF_DATE < TABLEA.ADD_TIME
)

1 row updated.

select * from tableb;

AS_OF_DAT         ID      VALUE
--------- ---------- ----------
28-FEB-19          1         -4
31-JAN-19          1         -4
31-DEC-18          1         -5
```

I changed the 2/29/2019 to 2/28/2019 in your sample data...

Presumably you really have multiple IDs in both tables, so correlate on that column two - instead of `WHERE ID = '1'` (which should probably be `WHERE ID = 1` anyway!) use `WHERE TABLEB.ID = TABLEA.ID`.

You could also use a merge instead of an update, e.g.:

```
merge into tableb b
using tablea a
on (a.id = b.id and b.as_of_date < a.add_time)
when matched then update set b.value = a.value;
```

or

```
merge into tableb b
using tablea a
on (a.id = b.id)
when matched then update set b.value = a.value
where b.as_of_date < a.add_time;
```

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I have multiple IDs and will make an update on that. For now, I was just trying to get one to work. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach suggest, that the column `ID`is a **primary key** of the `TABLEA`.

Please check if this is realy true, as otheriwse you should take care with constructions such as:

```
set VALUE =
(
  select VALUE from Table A
  where ID = '1'
  and TABLE B.AS_OF_DATE < TABLE A.ADD_TIME
)
```

In case that the subquery returns more that one row, you will immediately see
`ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

For *primary key* backed `TABLEA` you may use simple extension of your original query (adding a `WHERE` predicate):

```
update TABLEB 
set VALUE =
(
  select VALUE from TableA
  where ID = '1'
  and TABLEB.AS_OF_DATE < TABLEA.ADD_TIME
)
where TABLEB.AS_OF_DATE < (select ADD_TIME from TABLEA where ID = '1')
```

Note , that the duplicated row problem is relevant to the `MERGE` statement solution proposed in other answer, which works fine and elegant for unique `ID` in `TABLEA` but fails with `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables` on duplicated `ID`s.